# How do I use the Action Bar in Android 2.1

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Various websites about this topic explained. But I did not. Please explain step by step use action bar in android 2.1.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AppCompat from the support library.Download the Support library and import AppCompat to workspace. Its a Library project and you must reference the same in your Android project.

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Check **Adding libraries with resources** in the above link

Your Activity needs to `ActionBarActivity`. Need to use `Theme.AppCompat`

Check Adding ActionBar @

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

or You can use `ActionBarSherlock`.

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Answer (score 0):

in res/menu you will add xml file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:title="Refresh"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="Settings">
</item>
```

and then in Activity

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_refresh){

    }


    return true;
  }
```